# Fetch() authentication failed

Tags: javascript, authentication, digest

Originally we sent the authentication in the URL as

```
http://root:root@172.19.50.30/mjpg/video.mjpg?resolution=1024x768&compression=70
```

and that worked fine. As long as the password wasn't using special characters, this worked. But bad practice and Chrome forced me to do it differently.

The Wireshark header for this request:

```
GET /mjpg/video.mjpg?resolution=1024x768&compression=70 HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.19.50.30
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://172.19.50.30/local/ipsloitering/index.html?&language=en-US
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Digest username="root", realm="AXIS_00408CC561BC", nonce="7kRiObt8BQA=b937e181325fd66b88f1179eb1f5efe649c49e66", uri="/mjpg/video.mjpg?resolution=1024x768&compression=70", algorithm=MD5, response="5f31e9a6fe08992737bacd47bf4131a5", qop=auth, nc=00000001, cnonce="33c8306da3831b3a"
```

To allow for other characters, and use chrome, I used following JS Code:

```
fetch(url,
    {
    method:'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("root:root")
        },
    }
)
```

and the response is

```
GET /mjpg/video.mjpg?resolution=1920x1080&compression=70 HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.19.50.30
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://172.19.50.30/local/ipsloitering/index.html?&language=en-US
authorization: Basic cm9vdDpyb290
origin: http://172.19.50.30
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 11 Dec 2018 08:54:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.27 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2k
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="AXIS_00408CC561BC", nonce="LqVkObt8BQA=f5ede433bcdc7b2d1a7b12c0763156e9d45b8972", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
Content-Length: 381
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

How do I get the fetch() to use Digest, or what is causing this?

Comment: The answer to this totally depends on what is consuming this HTTP request and how this is configured.

Comment: What does that mean? (I am a C++ developer... I have little knowledge of HTTP).

Comment: It means whatever sever your calling will have kind of security configured, there are many different ways to do this, I (or anyone else) can't tell you how your servers security is configured, so we can't answer this question. That's not even to mention that you haven't stated what web hosting your using or where this resides. Is this IIS, apache, where does the server reside, is this using OAuth, pass though, what type of network is this, etc. etc.